# WORHP - Matlab interface, ERROR IN LEQSOL: symbolic step

Tags: matlab, worhp

I try to transform Hessian in `matlab handle` into Worhp structure. The idea is using random input to find nonzero-element in Hessian, something like:

```matlab
% Hessian
H = @(x)[x(1) x(2); x(2) 0];

% evaluate for some random points
nr = 3;
S = zeros(2,2);
for i=1:nr
    S = S + full(H(rand(2,1)) ~=0);
end

% get sparsity
S = S ~=0;

% convert everything to vectors for WORHP
[ HMrow, HMcol ] = find(S);
posCombined   = find(S);

hess2vec(rand(2,1),posCombined,H)

function hVec = hess2vec(x, mu, scale,posCombined,Hess) 
    H = Hess(x,mu, scale);
    hVec = H(posCombined);
end
```

And the `hess2Vec` is assigned to `wCallback.hm` in matlab-interface.

It works well with the given example, i.e. the example from [Maltab-interface](https://worhp.de/latest/), whose hessian is a 2x2 matrix

However it failed with an error by our own project:

```matlab
Error using worhp
WorhpIPLeqInit:  ERROR IN LEQSOL: symbolic step! flag =
-1

Error in worhp_interface (line 82)
[xFinal,lambdaFinal,muFinal,solverstatus] =
worhp(wData, wCallback);
```

Perhaps someone knows what that means? What might be the cause?

Comment: Can you try setting the parameter `MA97print` to 2 to get some additional information about the error?

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved by rearranging the elements of Hessian.First is the nonzero elements in triangle and then the diagonal elements.